ImageMagick Policy file correct but no effect
I use ubuntu 24.01
everything is installed correctly.
Moviepy,ImageMagick, all the libs that i need.
but when i try to generate TextClip with python
here is the error I am having.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-content/src/main.py", line 94, in <module>
    text_clip = TextClip(
                ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ubuntu/python-content/lib/python3.12/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 1146, in __init__
    raise IOError(error)
OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:
convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `@/tmp/tmpspctp73z.txt' @ error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3771.
.

I got this error.
I reviewed the documentation of ImageMagick and edited accordingly.
Even though i did that, it is still not functioning in the way i want.
Here is my policy.xml file:
Even though i gave the permission for the coder,it doesnt fix the issue.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
 ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<policymap>
  <!-- ImageMagick security policy configuration. -->
  
  <!-- Restrict memory usage to 256MiB -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
  
  <!-- Other default policies -->
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="16EiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/>
  
  <!-- Example default policy entries -->
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="cache"/>
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="config"/>
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="temporary"/>
  <policy domain="system" rights="none" pattern="PS"/>
  <policy domain="system" rights="none" pattern="PDF"/>
  <policy domain="system" rights="none" pattern="XPS"/>
  <policy domain="system" rights="none" pattern="MSL"/>
  <policy domain="system" rights="none" pattern="URL"/>
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="{MVG,TEXT,LABEL}"
</policymap>```

Here is the code:
for i in range(len(quote_parts)):
        startTime = words[i]['start']
        endTime = words[i]['end']
        duration = endTime-startTime
        
        
        

        for a in range(0,len(quote_parts[i])):
            text_to_show += quote_parts[i][a]
            letterDuration = 1/len(quote_parts[i])*duration
            if text_to_show.strip() == "":
                continue

            text_clip = TextClip(
                text_to_show.strip()  , fontsize=70, color='white', font='Bahnschrift-Bold', size=(1080, 1920),
                method='caption', align='center', stroke_color='black', stroke_width=2
            ).set_position((padding, 'center')).set_duration(letterDuration).set_start(startTime)
            startTime+=1/len(quote_parts[i])*duration
            text_clips.append(text_clip)
        print(i, len(words)-1)
        if i < len(words) - 1:
            next_start_time = words[i + 1]['start']
            pause_duration = next_start_time - endTime
            if pause_duration > 0:
                pause_clip = TextClip(
                    text_to_show.strip(), fontsize=70, color='white', font='Bahnschrift-Bold', size=(1080, 1920),
                    method='caption', align='center', stroke_color='black', stroke_width=2
                ).set_position((padding, 'center')).set_duration(pause_duration).set_start(endTime)
                text_clips.append(pause_clip)
        elif i == len(words) - 1:
            text_clip = TextClip(
                text_to_show.strip(), fontsize=70, color='white', font='Bahnschrift-Bold', size=(1080, 1920),
                method='caption', align='center', stroke_color='black', stroke_width=2
            ).set_position((padding, 'center')).set_duration(total_duration-endTime).set_start(endTime)
            print("duration",total_duration-endTime)
            print("start",endTime)
            text_clips.append(text_clip)
        text_to_show += " "


Where did you make the change?  What directory?  Do you have more than one Imagemagick installed -- IM 6 and IM 7?  Which one is TextClip using?  What kind of image is being used/read?  What was your command?  Why are you specifying "None" for the text? What are you trying to do with TextClip?

i install im6, i did the policy.xml change at the etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
I put png backgrounds to the video.I put the code to the question.I dont specify 'None' for the script,i put some words which are not None but it still says in that way.I am trying to make a video that has captions on it.I put the content and make the voice with ai.This exact script works in my pc, but not in ubuntu.I put the code to the question

Where in the code is the error message?  Post your full code, so that we can find line 96 where is indicates it failed.  Can you run TextClip outside of your video on a static image?  Does that even work?
